# D3 get data from database - php sends the data but on javascript null

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am using D3.js to create graphs. I have used d3.json function to get my data. But it is showing null on the Javascript side.

This is my code from HTML page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var id=[];
                d3.json("dataread.php", function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
   </script>
```

On the console it displays null.
The php file code is as follows:

```
<?php

$user="report"; 
$pass="report";  

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=report', $user, $pass);


$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT run_id from run');
$query->execute();

$data=$query->fetchAll();
$dbh=null;
echo "Hi";
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

When the page is loaded, I am getting the php data. I have attached an image showing it.

Please guide where am I going wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQDv.png)

Comment: When it is returning null?

Comment: your output is not a valid json, remove the `echo "Hi";` and it should be working... somehow

Comment: Yea it works!! My mistake. Didn't notice the hi at all.. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the

> echo "Hi"

from your code